# Convert a single column values into a single row in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have created a simple table which holds numbers as below:

```
CREATE TABLE saleshist (q1 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO saleshist VALUES (100);
INSERT INTO saleshist VALUES (101);
INSERT INTO saleshist VALUES (102);
INSERT INTO saleshist VALUES (103);

select * from saleshist
```

The above select shows  a single column like:

```
100
102
102
103
```

I wish to see the output like below:

```
100,101,102,103
```

Yes its a comma separated column value in a single row as a single value.
This is just an example that I had in mind and column values can be many.
I guess UNPIVOT can do this But I am not able to understand that properly. 
The best way I think of a solution to this is write a perl script and execute the query and then convert rows to columns with a comma separation.
Is there a direct way to do this in sql itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
select listagg(q1, ',') within group (order by null) from saleshist
```